# What are the pros and cons in serving CSS and JavaScript using Django template system

Tags: django, django-templates

Often, I encounter scenarios where I see it makes sense to use template tags in CSS and JavaScript files, such as the use of {{ STATIC_URL }} in CSS to access image. I understand the only way to achieve this is to have CSS and JavaScript files served by Django. I am interested in this approach. But before I commit, I want to hear you experts' experience on it. What are the pros and cons of this approach? Thx.

Comment: Well you would have overhead of view logic and template compilation etc. but I'd guess that shouldn't be much of a problem with small number of files and using Django's cache system. But I'd prefer using some kind of JavaScript compiler ([Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/) for example) and perhaps [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or something for CSS and serve them with some lightweight web server. You can also use relative paths for CSS images so you wouldn't really need {{ STATIC_URL }} there.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this as well. I've used dynamically generated JS/CSS with django before, it felt dirty and hacky, but at the same time, it made development and deployment easier.

Comment: Between relative paths for CSS images and the django.contrib.staticfiles app, you shouldn't need to use the django template engine just for resolving path issues.  If you have per-request dynamic CSS generation, you're setting yourself up for caching hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros:

- You can make a lot of per-request decisions about how things look and behave.
- You can keep the number of different CSS/JS files to a minimum.

Cons:

- Browsers tend to cache CSS and JS aggressively, so you'll need to use some aggressive anti-cache techniques.  Of course, this means disabling caching for some/all static files.
- Every CSS and JS request will consume another thread of your WSGI server.  In a normal request/response cycle, each request generally takes up one thread; you're effectively tripling this, at least, so now your app that could handle 200 simultaneous requests now can only handle 66.
- When your site makes it big, a CDN probably can't help you.

Alternatives:

- Tweak the CSS via javascript, and set a javascript variable inside your page template to control the tweaks.
- Use multiple CSS files and control their inclusion dynamically.
- Generate static files as needed, but then cache them to disk and serve them via mod_xsendfile.  This only works if you are serving static files from somewhere the django process can write to, such as on the same machine or a network mount.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've been sticking with the Django team's advice to make CSS and JavaScript static files, served directly by the server instead of via Django. It hasn't been a problem and has simplified a lot of things. Generally, any time I think I need a dynamioc CSS or JS file, there's a way to refactor so I don't.

For example:

> the use of {{ STATIC_URL }} in CSS to access image

I'm not sure how variable your `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is, but I've found that using the `<base>` tag in my pages fixes a lot of things. I assume this is for background images? Could you update your question to give an example?

Another thing I've done is, if my JavaScript needs dynamic data, I'll put most of the code in a JavaScript library I serve as a static file and then put the minimum dynamic stuff in a `<script>` tag at the end of the page. Usually I'll put it all in an object (looking a lot like JSON) and then just pass that object to a function. Come to think of it, you could just take all the dynamic stuff, make a dictionary out of it in your view function, encode it into JSON, and pass it via context. Then your page template just looks something like:

```
<html><head>
...
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/foo.js"></script>
...
</head><body>
...
<script>
    foo_main({{ foo_params_json|safe }});
</script>
</body></html>
```

This makes it a *lot* easier to reuse this code.